# style for disabled dates on primeNG calendar not working

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

I'm trying to add styling for some disabled dates on primeNG calendar, in the documentation it's suggested to use disabledDateTemplate. However, that does not seem to work and I couldn't find a single solution online either.

Answer (score 0):

you can overwrite the style of disabled date like this

*style.css*

```css
p-calendar td span.p-disabled {
  color: red !important;
  background: orange !important
}
```

[image: global theme]

or you can set a custom class so the style will not effect all component

*template*

```html
<p-calendar styleClass="custom-theme" 
            [(ngModel)]="dateValue" 
            [disabledDates]="invalidDates" 
            [disabledDays]="[0,6]" 
            [readonlyInput]="true">
</p-calendar>
```

*style.css*

```css
p-calendar .custom-theme  td span.p-disabled {
  color: #fff !important;
  background: darkred !important
}
```

[image]

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-demo-t2th9b?file=src/styles.css)

Comment: problem with this approach is dates im disabling using [mindate] attribute gets styled too. Also i want to style the dates by three different colours.

Comment: can you edit the demo to match your code so I can see your case correctly, you don't mention these problem in your answer 

Comment: yea i should have specified about the minDate, sorry about that. Anyways here is the forked stackblitz code,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-demo-b8cbeb?file=src/app/app.component.html as you can see dates that are disabled by midDate gets styled too. I want to style some specific disabled dates.